# installing xml editor in ubuntu 10.04(linux)

Tags: linux, ubuntu-10.04

Hey I have downloaded one of the xml editors from some site. 
But don't know how to install it in ubuntu 10.04
PLease help me at this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1:
Open the Ubuntu Software Center

Step 2:
Type "XML Copy Editor" or "xmlcopyeditor" on the search bar.

Step 3:
Click Install.

Or you want install exacly that you download?